# In QWOP what exactly is the action assigned to each key?

Tags: qwop

The QWOP interface screen says :

QW : thighs
OP : calves

However I still do not understand which actions, under which conditions, result from hitting those keys.
For example when I press P sometimes the right calf extends, sometimes it bends, sometimes it's the other calf.

Has anyone thought about writing down the rules of that game ? That might "break" its difficulty.

Answer (score 3):

After playing and watching for a little while, I believe the following functions are constant:

- Q: Right thigh forward, left thigh backward
- W: Left thigh forward, right thigh backward
- O: Extension of left calf, flexion (bending) of right calf
- P: Flexion of right calf, extension of left calf